# Access and modify Console.Readline() programmatically

Tags: c#, buffer, readline

In C# Console.ReadLine() implements history buffer of the previous strings read through the console. This buffer can be accessed by arrows up and down and also F7 button. Is there any way to access and modify this buffer programmatically within the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's not part of Console.Readline() - that's native to the operating system.  The command window does that whether or not you run a console app.

It MAY be possible to access that input buffer, but I don't think you're going to do it via standard CLR objects.  Instead I think you'll need to use unsafe access to the Win32 API (presuming you're on Win32).

This link talks about the Console and it's available functions and properties via the API but that's about all the help I can offer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't see any link you mentioned.

Comment: So very sorry, I thought I added the link but I forgot.  Mootinator got the right link.